# Cast unsigned long into signed short in PHP

Tags: php

In some other languages this problem is a matter of a simple cast. In PHP there's no such concept as all integers have the very same type (signed long long or signed long, architecture-dependent). Yet there are cases where you have to do that. E.g. `unpack()` cannot read `signed long` little endian byte order, only unsigned.

So, given an *imaginary* 32bit unsigned integer `4294967295`, how do I get a value for an *imaginary* signed 32bit integer from it? (That's `-1`.)

For example, [this can be done with `pack`/`unpack`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53368863/93540), but this seems suboptimal to me.

Is there a better way?

How about 32bit versions of PHP? (They tend to solve this problem "automatically" with an integer overflow, but I rather not to use this architecture-dependent workarounds. [Background.](https://github.com/pear/OLE/pull/10#issuecomment-436565763))

Comment: "Getting a signed 16bit integer" from it doesn't make a whole lot of sense, since as you say, PHP doesn't have that kind of number. All you'd get is another 32/64bit integer with a different value. You want to interpret the byte representation of the 32bit signed int as 16bit int…?

Comment: 'interpret the byte representation of the 32bit *un*signed int as 16bit signed int' - that's about it ([this issue](https://github.com/pear/OLE/pull/10#issuecomment-436565763))

Comment: so just fix your code: https://github.com/pear/OLE/blob/0519748fbcc20af69fe9f3ac5b37c941267e1343/OLE.php#L289
just use another format `unpack("v", fread($fh, 4));`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Comment: @Alex do you propose to unpack into a signed value and hope for the best, e.g. for an overflow? What if it does not happen?

Comment: I propose to have proper design and defined data flow. Your data is coming from some stream, and the only thing we should do - read stream data the way it was designed.

Comment: I'd like to have that too, but only if there's a way to unpack something into signed long (always 32 bit, little endian byte order) straight away. `unpack("v")`
does a different thing, it's for unsigned short

Answer (score 1):

For one, this can be done with `pack`/`unpack`:

```
$value = 4294967295;
$result = unpack("l", pack('L', $value));
var_dump($result[1]); // -1
```

[Try live.](https://3v4l.org/v6o9b)